# Regular Expression Library which supports both lookarounds and boolean "and"

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression program/library/anything which supports both boolean and as well as lookarounds.  The only library I've found that supports boolean "and" is dk.brics:
http://www.brics.dk/automaton/doc/index.html?dk/brics/automaton/RegExp.html

However this library does not support lookarounds, and it seems to be non-trivial to add  support.

There are many libraries that support lookarounds of course, but I haven't found any that also support boolean "and".

I'd be happy with anything that actually can run regular expressions, a library, a program, etc.

Comment: "And" is so easily implemented in regex - you shouldn't make that a requirement.  Look for lookaheads, and you can do 'and' with a positive lookahead:  /A&B/ => /(?=A)B/  Assert that the upcoming string matches A, then match B instead.  Thus, it must match both A and B.

Comment: I like this idea, but it seems to work only in simple cases.  For example if I wanted to match "a string with A and B followed by a string with C & D".  So I want /((.*A.*)&(.*B.*))((.*C.*)&(.*D.*))/ But if I translate that to:  /(?=.*A.*)(.*B.*)(?=.*C.*)(.*D.*)/ then it will match BCDA which is obviously not what I'm looking for.  Am I missing something?  Is there a way to use this technique in the more complicated cases as well?

Comment: Well, for that one you could use a lookbehind: `/.*B.*(?<=.*A.*)(?=.*D.*).*C.*/`  But, for a more general case: `/A&B/` => `/(?=A)B(?<=A)/`

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically couldn't you use negative checks along with an OR implementation to get the same functionality as the AND you are looking for?  In this case, I know .Net's regex parser supports OR and positive and negative look ahead and look behind.  To check that something matches A and B, check that it does not ( does not match A | does not match B).

Comment: It seems to me that your technique has the same problem I outlined above.

Comment: The exact syntax escapes me, but couldn't the situation you described above be handled by checking the first two groups for A | B with a validation that the second group differs from the first?  I realize that is probably an oversimplification of your original problem, so the pattern might not hold up in what you need, but I think it should address the presented issue.

Comment: Unforuntately I don't think I understand what you mean by "with a validation that the second group differs from the first". You're suggesting I do something like /(?=.*A|B.*)(.*A|B)(<some kind of assertion that the first group and the second group don't match the same thing?>)..../  -- if that's what you suggesting, then I don't think I know of any way to implement such an assertion in regular expressions, can you suggest a way to do this?  If that's not what you mean, then can you be more specific about what you mean?